# Access Viewport Overlay options using Python API

Tags: python

I am trying to access and change the viewport overlay panel options in Object Mode using python.
Specifically, I want to toggle the "Face Orientation" checkbox with python:

[image]

I thought I am able to access it using:

```
    bpy.data.screens["Scripting"].overlay.show_face_orientation
```

Turns out this does not work and raises an AttributeError.

[image: Blender Python API Error]

What do I have to do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `overlay` attribute is part of the [`bpy.types.SpaceView3D`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.SpaceView3D.html). Therefore you first need to iterate over the areas of the current screen and find the 3D View. Then you can search for the space in the area that has the `type` attribute set to `'VIEW_3D'` and is therefore of type `bpy.types.SpaceView3D`. If such a space exists you can access the `overlay` and through it `show_face_orientation`.

```
import bpy


for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        for space in area.spaces:
            if space.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                space.overlay.show_face_orientation = not space.overlay.show_face_orientation
                break
```

Note that you cannot set the overlay option  using the code above if you don't have an area with the 3D View open in the current screen.